# What's the best way to work on a website with a team collaboratively?

Tags: version-control

I am working on a website with a group of friends. The problem that we are having is that when any one of us wants to make a change in the code, we have to send the project back to one main person, who uploads it online.

Is there a tool available that would allow multiple team members to login from different locations and make changes to the website directly so that the website would be updated immediately after editing?

Thanks!

Comment: Something like github doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple different ways to address this issue.

To answer your question directly, Yes. There are tools that allow you to edit the website directly on the server, this depends a lot on where the website is hosted and how you can get access to it. If your server supports FTP or SFTP all you have to do is find an FTP client and get the correct credentials for your server to log in.

There are many editors out there that allow you to edit files over FTP or SFTP so it feels very much like you are just editing a file on your local machine. Personally I use Coda 2 which is on the Mac Platform, but there are many other choices.

Even though you can do this, its not usually the best way to go about creating a website with multiple developers. Here are some potential issues:

- **Working on the same file at the same time**: If you and a friend are working on the same file at the same time, its very easy to overwrite each others changes. If your friend saves to the sever and you don't get his changes before you save, you'll overwrite everything he just did.
- **Users are affected**: Once you launch your site, making live changes on the site creates a bad experience for users. Its way to easy to break stuff and you don't want users finding their way to a partially completed feature.

To solve these issues you'll want to look into some type of version control system like Git http://git-scm.com. and get a local development environment setup so you can run the site on your computer.

With git you can edit a specific part of the site on your local computer, push those changes anywhere you want like a staging server, your friends local site or even the production server if you want. git handles merging your changes in with your friends changes and much more. This way you can build full features locally then only push them up to the server when they are complete.